# How to fix this backsplash tiling job?

Tags: tiling

We purchased 1' x 1' tiling sheets. The tiles are about 2" x 1".
The tiling guys didn't use spacers everywhere. They taped the sheets and sometimes used spacers where the sheets met (and not everywhere they met).

[image: spacing issues 1]
[image: spacing issues 2]

Some of the tiles were also not flat with the plane of the other tiles.
[image: not flat with plane]

Also, how come there is so much thinset(?) between the tiles right now?  The grout hasn't even been applied.
[image: Too much thinset?]

How would all these issues be fixed?  We are going to be using a dark contrasting grout so all of these mistakes will be magnified.

**update 11/24**

The contractor basically removed individual tiles and fixed 99% of the tiles. 
We still haven't grouted yet. Going to carefully inspect. 
[image: fixed backsplash]

Comment: That's some pretty sloppy workmanship. A blacksplash is the visual center of a kitchen counter area, and should be done with great care. I'd be asking the contractor to repair it as trip0d199 suggests, plus a redo on the edging, which has a gap in the miter. Al in all, very poor.

Comment: One of the worst tile jobs I have ever seen. If that was in my house, I would be demanding a full refund and going elsewhere.

Comment: Echoing above that it's terrible workmanship. Have you considered a grout color that's very close to the tile color? That would diminish the inconsistency (though not make it go away).

Answer (score 4):

For the tile spacing issue, I don't think there is much you can do at this point short of ripping it all out and starting over.

For the tiles not set in plane correctly, I think you could carefully remove those tiles (just the individual tile), scrape out the hardened thinset behind them, and then re-apply with new thinset.

For the thinset squeezing out, perhaps you could grind that out with a oscillating tool with a grout removal attachment.